# Calling java method from c++ code, without passing any JavaVm

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I have **class** in C++ which **must** response for HTTP connection, that class must **establish connection**, **send responses** and do some other functions. This class is a part of huge project which I compile and finally get .so library for Android.

```
class HTTPSClient
{
public:
    WinHTTPSClient();

    ~WinHTTPSClient();

    bool Connect(const XMLString& a_strURL);
};
```

Now I want to call java functions from **Connect** function in c++. I have experiences in calling java functions from C++ code, but I always pass `JavaVM` to the class for example I call `init(JavaVM* javaVm);` and give as an argument javavm which comes from native code.

Now my question is: ***Can I call java method from C++ code without passing as an argument any JavaVm.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the JavaVM as a global/static variable of some class, e.g., by wrapping it up as a singleton. The variable can be accessed without explicitly passing it as an argument.

Comment: Can you bring some example please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Java Invocation API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html#11202) to create a VM directly in your native code.

Jim S.